# Login problems using NextJS and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, axios

I am doing a login using NextJS and TypeScript; but I cannot perform the corresponding login and redirection; Verifying the console, I correctly capture the inputs, and I verify with a console.log that the error is being generated by Axios (Network Error). I tried to make a POST request in Postman and I correctly receive the data via body from the backend, like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "dni": "..",
        "username": "..",
        "password": "..",
        "name": "..",
        "id": 1,
    },
    "token": ".."
}
```

And my code is like this::

```
const [access, setAccess] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  username: "", 
  password: "",
});
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
  username: "",
  password: "",
});

async function login(userData: {username: string, password: string}) {
  const { username, password } = userData;
  const URL = "http://.../auth/login";
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(URL + `?username=${username}&password=${password}`)
    
    if(response.data){
     const { access } = response.data;
       setAccess(true);
       access && router.replace('/dashboard');}
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
     if(error) throw new Error ("No se pudo verificar los datos")
  }
  
}
  useEffect(() => {
    !access && router.replace('/');
 }, [access]);

  const handleChange = (e: React.FormEvent) =>{
    const property = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).name;
    const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;

    setUserData({...userData, [property]: value});
    setErrors(validations({...userData, [property]: value}));
  } 

    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) =>{
    console.log("Envía datos", userData)
    e.preventDefault();
    login(userData);
  }
```

I also tried to perform with an endpoint like this:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://89.117.33.196:8000/auth/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
        });
        console.log("Response from external API:", response)
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          res.status(200).json(data);
        } else {
          res.status(response.status).json({ message: 'Error en la solicitud' });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error in API call:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error interno del servidor' });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(405).json({ message: 'Método no permitido' });
    }
  }
```

Replacing in the request inside my component const response = await axios.post('api/api',userData), but it always tells me axios errors like Error_network.

I tried inserting the console.log, replacing code, even watching several tutorials on the internet, but no one could help me.
I hope you can see the code and provide some alternative solution.

Axios error:
[image: Axios error]

Comment: You need to provide more details on what the nature of the network error is.

Comment: @possum You're right, at the bottom of the question I added a screen of the error, if that can help.